# Lock Embedded Resources in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, embedded-resource, resourcebundle

I'm developing on Cocoa using Xcode. I was wondering if there is a way to lock the embedded resources of my app, like logos, images, sounds, ... so nobody can change them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the easiest way would be to check timestamps on the resources, but this is also easy to circumvent. A better way would be to compute the hash of your application's resources directory on launch, and compare to a known value.

If any of the resources have been modified then the hash will differ and you can show a message and quit. You could use a custom build script step in Xcode to calculate the hash and have it available at compile time so that the process is all automated.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm familiar with hashing approach, I was looking to see if there is a built-in method in Xcode. Also the custom build script that you suggested is an interesting way to do it.